# Conversion between cv::Mat and arma::mat

Tags: opencv, type-conversion, armadillo, mlpack

I am using OpenCV and also want to add some of cool functions from [mlpack](http://www.mlpack.org), which is using [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html) matrices.

Is there an easy way to convet between cv::Mat and arms::mat?

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

OpenCV's `Mat` has a pointer to its data. Armadillo has a constructor that is capable of reading from external data. It's easy to put them together. Remember that Armadillo stores in column-major order, whereas OpenCV uses row-major. I suppose you'll need to add another step for transformation, before or after.

```
cv::Mat opencv_mat;    //opencv's mat, already transposed.
arma::mat arma_mat( reinterpret_cast<double*>(opencv_mat.data), opencv_mat.rows, opencv_mat.cols )
```

The `cv::Mat` constructor has a form that accepts pointer to data, and `arma::mat` has a function for a double* pointer to its data called memptr().

So, if you'd like to convert from `arma::mat` to `cv::Mat`, this should work:

```
cv::Mat opencv_mat( rows, cols, CV_64FC1, arma_mat.memptr() )
```

Comment: The code you've posted performs an implicit transposition, so if you have an OpenCV matrix that is row-major (i.e. one observation per row), then the Armadillo matrix you get back is column-major (one observation per column).  This is fortunate because mlpack expects column-major data for its algorithms. :)

Comment: It works! Thank you, a-Jays! But is there a way to convert from arma::mat to cv::Mat?

Comment: The `cv::Mat` constructor has a form that accepts pointer to data, and `arma::mat` has a function for a `double*` pointer to its data called `memptr()`. So, `cv::Mat opencv_mat( rows, cols, CV_64FC1, arma_mat.memptr() )` should work. Also, consider marking an answer accepted if it solves the problem.

Comment: Just a typo I spotted it should be `reinterpret_cast<double*>(opencv_mat.data)`, at least with my compiler. Other than this it worked fine, thanks!